# Asp.net - Orkut

Tags: asp.net

I am using asp.net, please let me know if their is any way I could show Orkut from my application. 
Like user could be able to login and then they can access orkut.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a 3LO (3-legger OAuth) library that allows you to do that via .NET using C#. The librery is called [orkut oauth api csharp](http://code.google.com/p/orkut-oauth-api-csharp/)